# array.reduce implementation through recursion

Tags: javascript, algorithm

i am trying to implement Array.reduce() method through recursion, it works for me

```js
var index = 0;
function reduce(arr, fn, initial) {
    if (index >= arr.length) {
        return initial;
    }
    if (!initial) {
        initial = arr[index];
        index++;
    }
    initial = fn(initial, arr[index], index, arr);
    index++;
    return reduce(arr, fn, initial);
}
```

but verifier doesn't accept my answer. What i did wrong?

Comment: Have you tried calling the function more than once?

Comment: `index` is stateful and will not be correct if you try to reduce more than one array.

Comment: @NickA oh, yeah, i got my mistake, thanks

Comment: @NinaScholz I didn't fully understand your question

Comment: @NickA what if i paste `index = 0` before `return initial;` ? Will it be bad practice?

Comment: @epsilon beats me, I'm not a fan of the `reduce` function, I prefer to just loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some issues:

- You defined `index` as a global variable which is never reset to 0, so if `reduce` is called more than once, it will have the wrong value. There are several solutions for this. I would suggest using the `this` value for keeping track of where you are.
- The `initial` argument is optional, but your code tests this with `!initial` which is not good enough: if the value of `initial` is 0 or any other falsy value, it should not be treated as being absent. Use `arguments.length` instead.
- When you increment the index because the `initial` argument was not provided, you don't check whether that index has become too large. The callback function should never be called with an invalid index. Swap the two `if` statements.
- When an empty array is passed with no initial value, `reduce` returns `undefined`, but it should throw an error as is the case with the native `reduce` method.
- When the array has "gaps" (i.e. it is a sparse array), the function still calls the callback function on those missing indexes. Instead those non-existing entries should not be iterated over. You can do this by using an array iterator, which only yields valid indexes.

Here is how you could deal with those issues:

```js
function reduce(arr, fn, initial) {
    // Get iterator for the indexes from `this`. 
    // The first time it will not be an iterator, so get it from arr.keys().
    const iter = Object(this).next ? this : arr.keys(); 
    let item = iter.next();
    if (arguments.length < 3) { // Solid check for presence of initial argument
        // Throw error when there's nothing to reduce
        if (item.done) {
            throw new TypeError("reduce of empty array with no initial value"); 
        }
        initial = arr[item.value];
        item = iter.next();
    }
    // Check end of array only after having dealt with missing initial value
    if (item.done) return initial;
    initial = fn(initial, arr[item.value], item.value, arr);
    return reduce.call(iter, arr, fn, initial); // Pass on the index via `this`
}

// Some test cases
console.log(reduce([1, 2, 3], (a, b) => a+b, 0), "should be 6");
console.log(reduce([1, 2, 3], (a, b) => a+b, 0), "should be 6");
console.log(reduce([1, 2, 3], (a, b) => a+b), "should be 6");
console.log(reduce([1], (a, b) => a+b), "should be 1");
console.log(reduce([1], (a, b) => a+b, 2), "should be 3");
console.log(reduce([], (a, b) => a+b, 1), "should be 1");
try {
    console.log(reduce([], (a, b) => a+b), "error");
} catch(e) {
    console.log("Error was raised as expected");
}
```

The `this` reference is private to the function and cannot be seen by the caller, so using it for propagating the current state (the iterator) seems ideal. The alternatives are:

- Using an extra argument
- Adding a property to either the array or the callback function argument.

The last option has as downside that this mutation can be detected by the caller. In the extreme case where the caller had frozen those objects, the code will even fail with an exception.

All solutions have any way one flaw: the original caller could pass a state via the initial call. So for each of the solutions, the caller could pass a specific value of the index (or iterator) like this:

- Pass an extra argument with a value -- let's say 5.
- Set the special `index` property of the function that is passed to `reduce` to have the value 5.
- Call `reduce` with `call` or `apply`, providing it a specific `this` value (an iterator).

There is nothing that can be done about this, since the requirement was to use recursion. Because of the recursion requirement there is nothing the function can do in the recursive call that the original caller could not do as well.

Comment: I learned a lot from your answer, some things I see for the first time (e.g. `Object(this).next` or `arr.keys()`), but I figured it out, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution could be to take the actual index into the functions arguments and check if the index exist in the array.

For a further recusion for finding the `initialValue` you need a symbol for an undefined value to ditinguish between an undefined and a non set value.

```js
function reduce(array, fn, initialValue, index) {
    index = index || 0;

    if (arguments.length === 0) {
        throw 'Reduce: No array';
    }

    if (arguments.length === 1 || typeof fn !== 'function') {
        throw 'Reduce: No function';
    }

    if (arguments.length === 2) {
        while (index < array.length && !(index in array)) {
            index++;
        }
        if (index in array) {
            return reduce(array, fn, array[index], index + 1)
        }
        throw 'Reduce: Empty array without initial value';
    }

    if (index >= array.length) {
        return initialValue;
    }

    return reduce(array, fn, index in array ? fn(initialValue, array[index], index, array) : initialValue, index + 1);                
}
   
// console.log(reduce());                     // throws Reduce: No array
// console.log(reduce([]));                   // throws Reduce: No function
// console.log(reduce([], (a, b) => a + b));  // throws Reduce: Empty array without initial value
console.log(reduce([], (a, b) => a + b, 42));
console.log(reduce([3, 4], (a, b) => a + b));
```

Comment: it works! i do exercises from [https://github.com/timoxley/functional-javascript-workshop], and it was neccesary to write a function with 3 args (`arr fn inital`), witthout `index`, but your solution is works)thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you have discovered, placing the index parameter outside the function leads to the complication that it must be continually managed for the function to work. I would think that usually, assignments to write functions assume they will be self-contained rather than rely on global variables.

We can conceptualize `reduce` recursively like this:

```js
function reduce(arr, fn, initial){
  if (!arr.length)
    return initial;

  if (arr.length == 1)
    return fn(initial, arr[0]);

  return reduce(arr.slice(1), fn, fn(initial, arr[0]));
}

console.log(reduce([1,2,3], (a,b)=>a+b, 0)); // 6
```

In JavaScript, each call to `slice` produces a copy of that section of the array, making this version less efficient for larger inputs. One option to improve efficiency could be to have an inner recursive function that relies on two parameters, an index and an accumulator, that would traverse the array, but I'm not sure the verifier would allow it since the outer function would no longer be calling itself.

One more thing to watch out for in your code is that `!initial` would catch whenever `initial` is a value that evaluates to "falsy," not only when it is not passed in as a parameter.

Here's a "hack"ish (because it modifies `fn`, although we could modify it back :), index-based solution that does not require an extra parameter and uses the full 4 parameters of `fn`:

```js
function reduce(arr, fn, initial){
  if (fn.index === undefined)
    fn.index = 0;
  else
    fn.index++;

  if (fn.index == arr.length)
    return initial;

  return reduce(arr, fn, fn(initial, arr[fn.index], fn.index, arr));
}

console.log(reduce([1,2,3], (a,b)=>a+b, 0)); // 6
```

Comment: you're right, but how can you pass index to `fn` args (in original `reduce` callback function has 4 args)? `!initial` checking is not a good idea, i got it, thanks!)

Comment: @epsilon functions in JS are objects. You could assign any arbitrary property to `fn` and you would not need an extra parameter as in Nina and trincot's solutions. That property would carry through and could be then updated on the fn object in the next call. To me, however, this suggestion, as well as trincot's use of `this`, iterables, or adding extra parameters seems a bit "hack"ish. I prefer purer functions with simple parameters where possible.

Comment: @epsilon I added an example with only three parameters that uses the full 4 parameters of `fn`.